# How to detect the monitor power state by VBScript/Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, winapi, vbscript

The objective is to find out the current monitor power status on Windows 7, which means I need to check the monitor is physically on or off.

I have found that [win32_desktopmonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394122(v=vs.85).aspx) contains a property named Availability, but it always return 3 even I have turned off my monitor.

What classes and properties should be adopted to VBScript/Batch?

Comment: Batch does not have any classes or properties.

Comment: @Squashman: Batch files can use `wmic`, a command-line wrapper for WMI.